# Change the WCF SOAP Response XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

There is an existing application which consumes a webservice. Now I want to make a new webservice for this application. I have no access to the source of this application. In the existing application it should be possible to just change the wsdl url definition and everything works as before.

So at least, I'm trying to prey an existing webservice. In that case the returned soap response must be the same as the existing one.
Now my question: How can I change the wcf soap response xml? 
For example if we create a new wcf project in VS we get the Service.svc. In this project there is a built in wcf test client:
[image]

With MessageContracts I can't accomplish what I want. 
With the IClientMessageInspector implementation I'm able to hook up the response soap xml and do changes but this only works from a separate client project. I want access this soap xml response in the same webservice project and do changes before it gets sent out to the wcf test client window.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IDispatchMessageInspector to modify the outgoing response.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms733104(v=vs.100).aspx

I.e. IDispatchMessageInspector is what is used to inspect (and modify) the messages on the server (applies to both incoming and/or outgoing messages).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement what I needed with the IDispatchMessageInspector. Wasn't easy though,